# How to concatenate declare date variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I concatenate declare date variables so they are in one column?  I need to show the dates as between dates. When I run the following I get an error message.

```
Declare @startdate date  = '20180101'
Declare @enddate   date  = '20180731'
SELECT
  'Dates'       =   @startdate+' - '+@enddate
FROM TABLE
```

**Error Message:**

> The data types date and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert them to strings before concatenating them.  For the default format on your system:

```
select dates = convert(varchar(255), @startdate) + ' - ' + convert(varchar(255), @enddate)
```

To specifically convert to YYYYMMDD use format `112`:

```
select dates = convert(varchar(255), @startdate, 112) + ' - ' + convert(varchar(255), @enddate, 112)
```

Comment: Works Great!  This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`concat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) :

```
SELECT CONCAT(@startdate, ' - ', @enddate) AS Dates
FROM TABLE;
```

Comment: Concat() is not a recognized built-in function on the Sql version I'm running.  Thanks.